# Use methods of a form from runtime-compiled code

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation

I have a program that have a log window (named `FormLog`), where I can easily write logs from other windows, using following syntax:

```
(Application.OpenForms["FormLog"] as FormLog).AddText(text);
```

My program also have ability to use user generated C# code, that will be compiled runtime, and it uses `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile` method. So basically user can change part of my code for special purposes (like fixing website crawling things). All this is already working fine.

The problem is, how can I access `FormLog.AddText` method from user generated code? I can find my `FormLog` from user generated code when I iterate through all open forms:

```
foreach (Form item in Application.OpenForms)
```

So `Application.OpenForms` method finds my `FormLog`, but I can't cast it as `FormLog` because for obvious reasons name `FormLog` is unknown form in user generated code (I get error `The type or namespace name 'FormLog' could not be found`). And if I don't cast it, then the method `WriteText` could not be found (`'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'WriteText'`).

So how can I access `FormLog.WriteText` method from code that is compiled at runtime?

I know this `Application.OpenForm` is not best approach to access other forms in general, but that's how it's already build, and I just try to get it working from user generated code.

Comment: Does the user generated code includes  the references to your assemblies?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do that, so currently no.

Comment: You can use `CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Path to Your Assembly that contains FormLog Class")`.

Comment: Sounds like the form needs to support an interface if you want to be able to access particular methods

Comment: I tried adding `parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase));` but that didn't help. I also added interface `IFormLog` that contains only `AddText` method and I casted `OpenForms["FormLog"] as IFormLog`, but getting `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Any code samples about how this can be done? I'm really stuck.